# Amstock chart event's text hiding at top

Tags: javascript, amcharts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymhUv.png

event box hiding and its balloon too .

balloon trying to open up on event box on mousehover.

is there any way to make padding from top to trendline ?

using AmStock chart v.3

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by setting minMaxMultiplier: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ValueAxis#minMaxMultiplier

for your value axis. If you are using JSON for chart config, add this to panel config:

valueAxes:[{minMaxMultiplier:1.05}]

if you do it using JavaScript API, then set:

var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valueAxis.minMaxMultiplier = 1.05;
panel.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

This will increase min and max of value axis by 5% and your event should fit.